# How to secure refresh token in React?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm using Django Rest Framework and simplejwt with a React frontend. Upon authentication the React application receives the Access and Refresh token.

According to best practices the frontend should store the Access Token in memory **but what about the Refresh Token?**

I can't find any information about this except that I should store the Refresh Token in a httponly cookie. IF that is the preferred way, how do I implement it with my current setup?

Comment: httponly cookies can't be set in javascript and would have to come from a backend server.  If you aren't able to have the backend to set/get it for you, you need to keep the refresh token in memory as well.  There's just not a lot of good options for SPAs for things like this.